# Not getting right date format in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get date and time in jQuery in number format for example,

**yyyyMMddhhmm or you can say    201404051159**

This is what I am trying,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var currentdate = new Date();
    var datetime = currentdate.getDate() + ""
                + currentdate.getHours() + ""
                + currentdate.getMinutes();

    alert(datetime);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YN2Xs/2/

It;s not giving me right date

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744299/how-to-get-datetime-in-javascript

Comment: missed to add `var currentdate = new Date()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems here.

First, you're using the `currentdate` variable without first declaring it. This is easy enough to fix by adding in `var currentdate = new Date();`

Second, the getter methods on a `Date` object don't return with leading zeros. This means you need to get the value and check if it's less than 9. If it is, you need to add in a leading zero.

Something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var currentdate=new Date() // Declare date variable 
  var datetime = "" + currentdate.getFullYear();
  var month = currentdate.getMonth() + 1; // Month is 0-11, not 1-12
  if (month < 10) {
    month = '0' + month;
  }
  datetime += month;
  var day = currentdate.getDate();
  if (day < 10) {
    day = '0' + day;
  }
  datetime += day;
  var hours = currentdate.getHours();
  if (hours < 10) {
    hours = '0' + hours;
  }
  datetime += hours;
  var minutes = currentdate.getMinutes();
  if (minutes < 10) {
    minutes = '0' + minutes;
  }
  datetime += minutes;
  var seconds = currentdate.getSeconds();
  if (seconds < 10) {
    seconds = '0' + seconds;
  }
  datetime += seconds;

  alert(datetime);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed to declare date variable

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var currentdate=new Date() // Declare date variable 
        var datetime = currentdate.getDate() + ""
                    + currentdate.getHours() + ""
                    + currentdate.getMinutes() + ""
                    + currentdate.getSeconds();

        alert(datetime);
    });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YN2Xs/1/)

Comment: The desired format was "yyyyMMddhhmm" you are outputting "ddhhmmss".

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to declare the date object to access date

```
 var date=new Date();
    var datetime = date.getDate() + ""
                + date.getHours() + ""
                + date.getMinutes() + ""
                + date.getSeconds();
```

Find the fiddle link:

http://jsfiddle.net/ShinyMetilda/7pHj3/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var currentdate = new Date();
    var datetime = currentdate.getFullYear()
                + currentdate.getMonth() 
                + currentdate.getDate()
                + currentdate.getHours()
                + currentdate.getMinutes()

    alert(datetime);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could break it down like so

DEMO1 http://jsfiddle.net/YN2Xs/5/

OUTPUT1  `20143593653`

DEMO2 http://jsfiddle.net/YN2Xs/7/ (2 digit with zeros)

OUTPUT2 `2014030595829`

EXAMPLE1

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var currentdate=new Date()
        var datetime = 
                    + currentdate.getFullYear() + ""
                    + currentdate.getMonth() + ""        
                    + currentdate.getDate() + ""
                    + currentdate.getHours() + ""
                    + currentdate.getMinutes() + ""
                    + currentdate.getSeconds();

    });
```

EXAMPLE2 with 2 digit day and month adding `0` where required

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var currentdate=new Date();
        var month = currentdate.getMonth();
        var day = currentdate.getDate();
        if(month < 10){ month = '0' + month}
        if(day < 10){ day = '0' + day}

        var datetime = 
                    + currentdate.getFullYear() + ""
                    + month + ""        
                    + day + ""
                    + currentdate.getHours() + ""
                    + currentdate.getMinutes() + ""
                    + currentdate.getSeconds();

        $('input').val(datetime);

    });
```

EDITED

`getFullYear()` replaced `getYear()`

Comment: for me output is 1143593853