# Converting to a Date Object from a datetime-local Element

Tags: javascript, html, forms, date, datetime

I am using the HTML5 element datetime-local. I need to have two formats of the date. One as a date object the other as a string. I am going to store the date object in the database and I am going to use the string to set the datetime-local form input.

I need to convert this string to a date object:
**"2014-06-22T16:01"**

I can't seem to get the correct time. This is what I am getting. The time not correct.
**Sun Jun 22 2014 09:01:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)**

This is the how I am formating the date:

```
function formatTime(_date) {
var _this = this,
    date    = (_date) ? _date : new Date(),
    day     = date.getDate(),
    month   = date.getMonth() + 1,
    year    = date.getFullYear(),
    hour    = date.getHours(),
    minute  = date.getMinutes(),
    seconds = date.getSeconds(),

function addZero(num) {
  return num > 9 ? num : '0' + num;
}

minute  = addZero(minute);
seconds = addZero(seconds);
hour    = addZero(hour);

day     = addZero(day);
month   = addZero(month);

return year + '-' + month + '-' + day + 'T' + hour + ':' + minute;
```

};

Example:
http://codepen.io/zerostyle/pen/gwpuK/

Comment: for UTC, ISO issues, I think you have already got an answer. For Date Formatting, please check this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744299/how-to-get-datetime-in-javascript/24328303#24328303

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to get an ISO 8601 date string, you can try [*Date.prototype.toISOString*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.43). However, it always uses UTC. If you want to include the local timezone, use something like the following:

```
/* Return a string in ISO 8601 format with current timezone offset
** e.g. 2014-10-02T23:31:03+0800
** d is a Date object, or defaults to current Date if not supplied.
*/
function toLocalISOString(d) {

   // Default to now if no date provided
   d = d || new Date();

  // Pad to two digits with leading zeros
  function pad(n){
    return (n<10?'0':'') + n;
  }

  // Pad to three digits with leading zeros
  function padd(n){
    return (n<100? '0' : '') + pad(n);
  }

  // Convert offset in mintues to +/-HHMM
  // Note change of sign
  // e.g. -600 => +1000, +330 => -0530
  function minsToHHMM(n){
    var sign = n<0? '-' : '+';
    n = Math.abs(n);
    var hh = pad(n/60 |0);
    var mm = pad(n%60);
    return  sign + hh + mm;
  }

  var offset = minsToHHMM(d.getTimezoneOffset() * -1);

  return d.getFullYear() + '-' + pad(d.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + pad(d.getDate()) +
         'T' + pad(d.getHours()) + ':' + pad(d.getMinutes()) + ':' + pad(d.getSeconds()) +
         '.' + padd(d.getMilliseconds()) + offset;
}

console.log(toLocalISOString(new Date())); // 2014-06-23T07:58:04.773+0800
```

#### Edit

The above probably misses your question, which seems to be;

> I need to convert this string to a date object: "2014-06-22T16:01"

Presumaly you want to treat it as a local time string. ECMA-262 says that ISO–like strings without a timezone are to be treated as UTC, and that is what your host seems to be doing. So you need a function to create a local Date object from the string:

```
function parseYMDHM(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D+/);
  return new Date(b[0], --b[1], b[2], b[3], b[4], b[5]||0, b[6]||0);
}

console.log(parseYMDHM('2014-06-22T16:01')); // Sun Jun 22 16:01:00 UTC+0800 2014
```

Comment: I might not have communicated my problem right. The main problem is the time that get's set is 5 hours off.  The time is getting converted to the future. What am I missing?