# Date and time in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get the date and time in javascript as 12/08/2015-1:49? I tried the following but I get an error `TypeError: now.format is not a function`

```
var now = new Date();
now.format("dd/mm/yy-h:mm tt");
console.log(now); //TypeError: now.format is not a function
```

Comment: What make you think that there is a `format` method ? [mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/prototype)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: @Hacketo thanks. [This is where I got that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744299/how-to-get-datetime-in-javascript)

Comment: this post is talking about dependency that you need to download and include in your project

Comment: and the dependency in question modifies Date.prototype, this is generally considered bad (read: awful) practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no any `format` method for `Date` in JavaScript. Either you need to use any other external libraries like [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/), or write your own script to format.

Here is example how you can convert date to dd/mm/yy-h:mm tt format

```js
    var now = new Date();

    var date = now.getDate() + "/" + (now.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + now.getFullYear() + "-" + now.getHours() + ":" + now.getMinutes() + " " + (now.getHours() > 12 ? "PM" : "AM");

    console.log(date)
```

Comment: You might be able use `now.getFullYear()` instead of `(1900-now.getYear()) `

Comment: @Becky, yes you can use that also. Thanks for reminder.

Comment: @LaxmikantDange also `(1900-now.getYear())` should be `(1900+now.getYear())`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function getFormattedDate() {
    var date = new Date();
    var str = date.getDate() + "/" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + date.getYear() + "-" +  date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes() + " " + date.getSeconds();
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Extend Date`s prototype, add function format

```
  Date.prototype.format = function(format){
    format = format || "Y/M/D H:I:S";
    var data = {
      y: this.getFullYear() % 100,
      Y: this.getFullYear(),
      m: this.getMonth() + 1,
      d: this.getDate(),
      h: this.getHours(),
      i: this.getMinutes(),
      s: this.getSeconds()
    };
    var needAddZeroLTTen = "mdhis".split('');
    for(var i = 0; i < needAddZeroLTTen.length; i ++){
      var prop = needAddZeroLTTen[i];
      data[prop.toUpperCase()] = data[prop] < 10 ? ('0' + data[prop]) : data[prop];
    }
    var dateStr = format;
    for(var i in data){
      var reg = new RegExp(i,'g');
      dateStr = dateStr.replace(reg, data[i]);
    }
    return dateStr;
  }
```

Then use below code to format a date

```
var date = new Date();
var dateStr = date.format('D/M/y-h:I');
```

Answer (score 0):

the best way to manage dates in js is using http://momentjs.com/ here you will find a great way to format the dates

Answer (score 0):

You can either

- do this by hand by using the functions on Date like date.getMonth(), however these do not support zero padding, and it gets quite fiddly. Only do this if you cannot include a third-party library, you're obsessive about load time / performance or you really enjoy re-inventing the wheel.
- Use a third-party library like [moment](http://momentjs.com/), this has multiple formats and supports padding, e.g. MM will force month as two characters.

Example

```
var now = new Date();
console.log(moment(now).format("DD/MM/YY-hh:mm Z"));
```

Answer (score -1):

Moment.JS would help you.
Please take a look on this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f3zp5zuv/

```
alert (moment('2015 Apr 30').format('DD/MM/YY -h:mm'))
```

Moment: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/

```js
alert (moment('2015 Apr 30 14:42:00').format('DD/MM/YY -h:mm'))
```

```html
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```