# How to build Time object using a date string as Local Time

Tags: javascript, date

All:

Thanks for help. I wonder how can I build a Date object using local time string, for example:

If I use new Date("2016-07-01"), what I want to build is

`2016-07-01 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)` (say I am in San Francisco),

but right now, it gives me something like

`Thu Jun 30 2016 16:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)`

Any idea?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744299/how-to-get-datetime-in-javascript

Comment: @amflare Thanks, but sorry I guess I did not quite catch ur point, the problem I try to describe is when I use a Date/time string, the new Date() always treat it as from UTC time zone, I try to make that time as indicating my local time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20834878/5937428

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22184747/parse-string-to-date-with-moment-js

Comment: @AnthonyAstige Thanks, could you give one example how can I build a time object which indicate 2016-01-01 00:00:00 in San Francisco local. with "2016-01-01" only?

Comment: https://github.com/rhroyston/clock-js

Answer (score 0):

To convert the default UTC time created from running `new Date(dateString)`:

```
const MILLISECONDS_PER_MINUTE = 60000;
const utcDate = new Date('2015-01-01');
console.log(new Date(utcDate.getTime() + (utcDate.getTimezoneOffset() * MILLISECONDS_PER_MINUTE))); // Wed Jan 01 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (MST)
```

Comment: Thanks, but sorry I guess I did not quite catch ur point, the problem I try to describe is when I use a Date/time string, the new Date() always treat it as from UTC time zone, I try to make that time as indicating my local time.