# How to convert date in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I try to use `new Date()` in javascript, and it display like this

```
Sat Dec 17 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (your country standard time)
```

but I want to convert to display like this

```
2020-02-05T06:23:34
```

I try to search it in google but I don't know the term that Im gonna use to search the date.

Comment: Take a look at: https://momentjs.com/

Comment: i think similar thing is mentioned here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744299/how-to-get-datetime-in-javascript

Comment: Look for 'Format Date', I quickly found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/34015511/3123057

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Following Methods:

```
let date = new Date().toISOString().slice(0,19)
```

or

```
let date = new Date().toJSON().slice(0,19)
```

You can find similar methods from here:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toisostring.asp

Answer (score 4):

```
new Date().toJSON().slice(0,19)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Date.toISOString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)

> The timezone is always zero UTC offset, as denoted by the suffix "Z"

```js
console.log(new Date(`Sat Dec 17 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0800 `).toISOString())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use moment.js library for that

```js
var date=new Date();

let c=moment(date).format();
console.log(c)
let s=c.split("+")
console.log(s[0])
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry, theres proper options available in vanilla. Commented on question

Answer (score 0):

With vanilla JS you could use `toISOString`.
Go ahead and try

`(new Date()).toISOString();`.

Output would be in this format: `"2019-02-01T05:43:11.618Z"`.

If you don't need the time zone you can format it, or use character handling.

Otherwise, use a library like [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) or [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/) to handle date formatting.